# PHP - stripping the extension from a file name string

Tags: php, string

I want to strip the extension from a filename, and get the file name - e.g. file.xml -> file, image.jpeg -> image, test.march.txt -> test.march, etc.

So I wrote this function

```
function strip_extension($filename) {
   $dotpos = strrpos($filename, ".");
   if ($dotpos === false) {
      $result = $filename;
   }
   else {
      $result = substr($filename,0,$dotpos);
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Which returns an empty string.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You’re not doing anything wrong. This function works fine (I just did a copy-paste test). Something is therefore wrong with the code that you are not showing us. Of course, the other answers here are “better” in some sense, but you asked what you’re doing wrong. BTW, I’d have written ```function strip_extension(string $filename) : string {```.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking for [`pathinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) i believe. From the manual:

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

Result:

```
/www/htdocs/inc
lib.inc.php
php
lib.inc
```

*Save yourself a headache and use a function already built. ;-)*

Comment: You beat me to it by 35 seconds :P

Comment: Problem is, the OP only has the file **name**, not the full **path to the file**.

Comment: @dosboy: :blows off fingers and re-holsters them to side: ;-)

Comment: Heck, i am ninja'd but i have own examples :)

Comment: My bad, I thought `pathinfo()` only worked with valid paths/files. Owned :x

Answer (score 8):

You should use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) which is made to do that.

**Example:**
Things used: [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$name = 'file.php';

$pathInfo = pathinfo($name);

echo 'Name: '. $pathInfo['filename'];
```

Results:

```
Name: file
```

---

**Example 2 (shorter)**

```
$name = 'file.php';    
$fileName= pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME );

echo "Name: {$fileName}";
```

Results:

```
Name: file
```

---

**Live examples:**
[No. 1](http://codepad.viper-7.com/L7ay3C) | 
[No. 2](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IvfA9n)

Comment: Thank you for this...Example 2 saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

This very simple function does the trick:

```
function strip_extension($filename)
{
    $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $regexp = '@\.'.$extension.'$@';
    return preg_replace($regexp, "", $filename);
}
```

Comment: You escape the escape character? Is that necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short one. Just know if you pass a path, you'll lose the path info :)

```
function stripExtension($filename) {
   return basename($filename, '.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/q11OJV0u).

The only real advantage of this one is if you are running < PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
function strip_extension($filename){
  if (isset(pathinfo($filename)['extension'])) { // if have ext
    return substr($filename, 0, - (strlen(pathinfo($filename)['extension'] +1)));
  }
  return $filename;  // if not have ext
}
```

You must verify if the filename has extension to not have errors with pathinfo. As explained in http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: You can just use `pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` to get a string back instead of needing to call isset() on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient, but it actually answers the question.

```
function strip_extension($filename){
    $f = array_reverse(str_split($filename));
    $e = array();
    foreach($f as $p){
        if($p == '.'){
            break;
        }else{
            array_push($e,$p);
        }
    }
    return implode('',array_reverse($e));
}
```